# Spring MVC Validator. encapsulate multiple validator initialization for multiple request mappings

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have a some controllers that have multiple methods, each with a different `@RequestBody` domain object having its own validator

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private Validator BeanOneValidator;

    @Autowired
    private Validator BeanTwoValidator;

    @Autowired
    private Validator BeanThreeValidator;

    @InitBinder("BeanOne")
    private void initBeanOneBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(beanOneValidator));
    }

    @InitBinder("BeanTwo")
    private void initBeanTwoBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(beanTwoValidator));
    }

    @InitBinder("BeanThree")
    private void initBeanThreeBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(beanThreeValidator));
    }

    @RequestMapping(...)
    public requestWithBeanOne(@RequestBody @Valid BeanOne){...}
    @RequestMapping(...)
    public requestWithBeanTwo(@RequestBody @Valid BeanTwo){...}
    @RequestMapping(...)
    public requestWithBeanThree(@RequestBody @Valid BeanThree){...}
}
```

Is there a way to register multiple binders for a controller like they are here without declaring multiple @InitBinder annotated methods?

Doing something like this doesn't work:

```
    @InitBinder({"BeanOne","BeanTwo","BeanThree"})
    private void initBeanOneBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(beanOneValidator, beanTwoValidator, beanThreeValidator));
    }
```

If there was a way to register the validators globally without having to add the explicit `@InitBinder` method to the controller that would suffice as well.

Comment: Why would you even validate your beans in such a way (via InitBinder's)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `ControllerAdvice` to your application that registers your validator globally:

```
import org.springframework.validation.DataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidatorAdvice {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(DataBinder dataBinder) {
       // dataBinder.addValidators();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get Invalid target for Validator